# SISS doesn't finish insert when there is 34.000 rows, my DB may have some kind of limitation?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created a package in my SISS that makes a insert in differents databases, the table is the same.

But my package doesn't finish when I have a lot of rows, it keeps running forever.

I have noticed that for a database located in another instance this problem doesn't occurs, I don't know, maybe my database doesn't allow a huge insert?

I did some test trying insert less rows and my package work well. I thing that my problem may be some role in my db ...

[Flow of integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSEAC.png)

Comment: By "running forever", which step was your data flow task stuck at?

Comment: My guess would be blocking or locking on the database. This should probably go to the DBA SE site

Comment: The first step is read the data on my source table, it reads more or less 1690 rows and goes to second step (that is writing) but it keeps running the "insert statement" and doesn't finish.

Comment: An error I experienced is that the Source and Destination was accidentally made the same. In short, the SSIS package was inserting the table contents back into the table, creating a never-ending loop of inserts. Double check that isn't the issue

Comment: I checked this, the name of the table and the types of my columns are the same, but the destination is in another database. I did some tests here and discoved that when I disabled the option "Table lock" it worked normally.

But I don't realy know if I should disable this option.

Comment: The table lock option will lock entire the table using an exclusive lock while it is being loaded.  Is the destination table updated by another process while the data is loaded into it, and do you want only the package to access this table while it is loaded?

Comment: @userfl89 answering your question... no, my destination is not update by another process. I think that the most safe option for me is keep my table locked at least while my package is making the insert or update operation. Only after that the other process (trigger / stp) could read my table.

But my problem is, when I let the option "Table lock" o SISS doens't finish the operation ... I don't know why this happens, with other tables I didn't have this problem, I could load a lot of data without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what is the source of the data.

Thanks

Comment: My source is a view that I have created to control if the data already exists on my destination or not.

Comment: what is source file type whether excel or any other source